# addEventListener() method id is not working in IE 11.0.12, seems to be working in 11.0.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

addEventListener() method id is not working in IE 11.0.12, seems to be working in 11.0.10 .Below is the code which id working in IE 11.0.10 but not in IE 11.0.12 .Help me out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to a button.</p>

    <button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);

    function displayDate() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're running this against an intranet (local) address, you're running into IE's *very surprising* behavior of going into "compatibility" mode with intranet addresses. This very-misnamed mode makes the browser incompatible with standards by trying to make it compatible with earlier versions of IE.

To fix it, add:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

to the `head` element to tell IE that the page expects to be run in standards mode. (I suspect this isn't to do with IE10 versions at all, but just different test pages that are or are not on your intranet, or do or do not have the `meta` tag. That, or you had previous changed the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" option in IE 11.0.10 and then when IE 11.0.12 was installed, it reset the option.)

---

Separately, although your code works for me in IE 11.0.9600, to be as broadly-compatible as possible, add the third argument to `addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate, false);
// Here ----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Up-to-date browsers make that optional (again, including IE 11.0.9600 in my test), but it used to be required and so some older browsers may fail when it's not there.